# CentOS as windows 7 drive

Tags: networking, centos, ssh, mappeddrive

i have a server, which i usually connect through ssh(password), the server is on a network and runs CentOS, but i work from a windows 7 computer. i have been searching to create a network drive through ssh, but i wanted to know which is the fastes and reliable way to work on the server as a Drive from windows, sftp/ftp/samba/etc?

the server is only for tests, so it doens't need to have many security features.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the files on the CentOS server from your Windows machine, so that you can manipulate files directly on the server? Or are you asking something else? Your question seems confusing.

Comment: i have been working with SSH compatible applications, "Coda", where i could connect to SSH and i get a tree view with the server files, and could edit and save on the server, but now, the applications(on windows 7) i need, doesn't support ssh, ftp or network files... i wanted to know if the fastest and reliable way to work is to try to map a drive from ssh,ftp, network share(samba), or any other way

Comment: You should check out WinSCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of people aren't going to like that I answer this for you, but here 
it is.  If you need to share with samba from CentOS 6.2, you will need to
 do the following (plus or minus a few steps):

```
1.  Allow port 445 and 138 through your IPTables firewall or turn
    off the IPTables service.
2.  Possibly demote SELinux to "permissive" mode using the SELinux 
    management GUI (that you can download), then reboot.
3. Enable SMB as a service in the services manager.
4. Edit /etc/smbusers  so it contains one of the non-root user accounts
    on your system.
5.  Change smb config:
   a. security=share
   b.  set "write list = +username"  in smb.conf
   c. set browseable = yes in smb.conf
   d. set writable = yes
   e.  set public =yes
   f. think about setting "hosts allow = 192" (or something similar for 
      at least some amount of security)
```

Then, finally, use Windows 7 to map the drive to the machine.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to share the volume using Samba and map the drive on the Windows client. No need to involve SSH if you're on the same network.